# How to change Output path in Visual Studio for all projects of a Solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to change the output path for all the projects under same solution for a C# application. I'm manually setting this for all the projects one by one. There are around 40 projects so, so its very to do this for all the projects. I need to change this output path very frequently.

I have one way to do this by running a script which will set output path for all the `csproj` file from `ADir` to `BDir` under this solution file.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'PFx86|x86'">
<OutputPath>ADir</OutputPath>
```

Or I can create a new `Configuration` for `ADir`.

So is there any shortcut way to do this in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: How about doing a "[Replace in files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Searching_And_Replacing)" in all *.csproj files with e.g. [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)? Simply search for `ADir` and replace it with `BDir`. Be sure to have a backup (e.g. check into your SVN/Git) before doing the replacements.

Comment: @UweKeim - is there something specific about Notepad++ that would do it better than Visual Studio itself (which we know, by definition, they already have)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Just the fact that if you do it while having the solution itself open, it keeps popping up "Reload project" messages boxes arount 40 times.

Comment: unless you click 'Reload All'.. Anyway, standard way of doing this: make all your projects Import the same property sheet and set the path in there

Comment: I'm asking that If its possible to do in visual studio? I know I can do this by notepad++ or I can write some script.

Comment: @stijn what do u mean by Import the same property sheet and set the path in there. Could u please explain.

Comment: You create an msbuild file which defines OutputPath (or whatever property you want to override, therein lies the power of this solution), then use an editor to add an Import statement for that file at the end of each project file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx. You cannot do this from within VS obviously, but it's the tried and tested way to apply something to all project files.